# Custom patterns in logstash that make logstash stop compiling

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'd written a regular expression for the particular date format in my log (created ./patterns directory and file custom_time_pattern in it):

Date format: 2013-11-05T12:05:46.123456+03:00

```
CUSTOMTIMESTAMP ([0-9]{4,4})\-([0-9]{2,2})\-([0-9]{2,2})([A-Za-z])(:?2[0123]|[01]?[0-9])(:?[0-5][0-9])(:?(:?[0-5]?[0-9]|60)(:?[:.,][0-9]+)?)(\+?([0-5][0-9]):?([0-9][0-9]))
```

And then I used it in my filter:

```
filter {
    if [type] == "syslog" {
        grok {
            patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
            remove_tag => ["_grokparsefailure"]
            match => {
                "message" => ["%{CUSTOMTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}", "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}", "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(\(etc/cron\.hourly\))(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}) %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}", "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\]) %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}"]
            }
   add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
   add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
        }
    }  
}
```

And logstash stopped working (a.k.a. it doesn't compile anymore).

The problem is that with adding custom patterns logstash stops compiling entirely. And by trying out some options, I got that the problem is in that part: "%{CUSTOMTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp}". But I don't get the reason.

Comment: The pattern is fine, so the problem is somewhere with how you used it.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't get where exactly, cause for me it seems that everything is fine with syntax.

Comment: The problem might be with the `message` pattern: there are too many `%{DATA}`s.

Comment: No, it worked well before without the first (message => ["%{CUSTOMTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}"]...), but with (message => ["%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}"]...). Not to mention that message is made for parsing, so any amount of %{DATA}s should be possible.

Comment: Basically everything was parsing not so bad, but I needed new pattern for new portion of logs as they have different time format. And as soon as I added CUSTOMTIMESTAMP for parsing new type of logs, logstash stops compiling when it gets CUSTOMTIMESTAMP in the message field. (patterns_dir => ["./patterns"] seems to have no effect, btw. Logstash keeps running.)

Comment: You should understand that behind the scenes, all `%{DATA}` are translated into `.*?` and `%{GREEDYDATA}` are translated into `.*`.  These kind of patterns cause "expansion"/"backtracking" and are thus very resource consuming. It is best to define your patterns in a more verbose way (to only match the required character type). Anyway, it is impossible to debug the pattern without an exact input you have trouble with.